# running jar that references another jar

Tags: java, jar, classpath, aix

Trying to run a jar from the command line that references another jar.

I am able to run the jar without referencing the other jar fine by:

```
/usr/java6/bin/java -cp /u/me/bin/MyJar.jar com.mypackage.myprogram.ContainsMain
```

Now if I need to add another jar that MyJar reference so I try this but it fails:

```
/usr/java6/bin/java -cp /u/me/bin/MyJar.jar;/u/me/bin/OtherJar.jar com.mypackage.myprogram.ContainsMain
```

I get the error: OtherJar.jar: cannot execute

It seems like as soon as I put a ';' in the -cp argument it fails

I'm on an AIX box if that matters

File permissions are set to 777 on both jar files

Comment: Just a side note: your life probably becomes a lot easier if you look into turning MyJar into an executable jar. When done properly, it becomes as easy as running java -jar MyJar.jar even when you have a hundred library dependencies. Something to look into in the near future, I thought I'd mention it to prevent the belief that Java is always this cumbersome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Unix/Linux/related, the path separator is not `;`, but `:`. Revise your command-line to:

```
/usr/java6/bin/java -cp /u/me/bin/MyJar.jar:/u/me/bin/OtherJar.jar com.mypackage.myprogram.ContainsMain
```

Comment: On additional note - ; is command separator on unix, so you are running two commands here -
    /usr/java6/bin/java -cp /u/me/bin/MyJar.jar;
AND 

    /u/me/bin/OtherJar.jar com.mypackage.myprogram.ContainsMain

Answer (score 2):

Since you're on a Unix platform, your `classpath` separator should be a colon, not a semicolon.

This:

```
/usr/java6/bin/java -cp /u/me/bin/MyJar.jar;/u/me/bin/OtherJar.jar com.mypackage.myprogram.ContainsMain
```

is [interpreted by the shell as two commands](http://sayle.net/book/basics.htm#grouping_commands) separated by a semicolon, hence your error.